# Is there a simpler way to write the limit I need?

Tags: math-mode

I would like to write this kind of limit and I found a sloppy way to do it, but does anybody know a simpler way of writing this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\newcommand*{\bfrac}[2]{\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}


                $${\lim_{\bfrac{x\to a}{<}}{f(x)}} \text{ and } {\lim_{\bfrac{x\to a}{>}}{f(x)}}$$

\end{document}
```

[image: Limits]

Comment: Please clarify the intended meaning of the two types of limits. Are you maybe looking to express the idea that the limit is taken as `x` approaches `a` from either below or above? Please advise.

Answer (score 13):

I'd define suitable commands:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\gto{\underset{>}{\to}}
\newcommand\lto{\underset{<}{\to}}

\begin{document}

\[
\lim_{x\lto a} f(x)
\text{ and }
\lim_{x\gto a} f(x)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Side note.* You seem to abound with braces. Avoid it.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: And thank you for the braces tip, I have taken out half of them and nothing changed to de document.

Answer (score 13):

In addition to upright arrows and greater- and less-than signs below the arrow, the left- and right-hand limits are, according to the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-sided_limit), sometimes denoted with:

- a superscript plus or minus sign:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \begin{document}
  \[ \lim_{x\to a^{+}} f(x) \text{ and } \lim_{x\to a^{-}} f(x) \]
  \end{document}
  ```

  [image]
- a slanted arrow (`\nearrow` and `\searrow`):

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \begin{document}
  \[ \lim_{x\nearrow a} f(x) \text{ and } \lim_{x\searrow a} f(x) \]
  \end{document}
  ```

  [image]

Comment: second code block is the same as the first.

Comment: @ScottSeidman sorry, I was daydreaming

Answer (score 7):

I will assume that you're looking to express the notion of taking the limit of `f(x)` as `x` approaches `a` either from below or from above. If this assumption is correct, I believe it's quite common to use `\uparrow` and `\downarrow` instead of `\rightarrow` (also known as `\to`) to express the "one-sidedness" of the limit being taken.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for '\text' macro
\begin{document}
\[
\lim_{x\uparrow a}f(x) \text{ and } \lim_{x\downarrow a}f(x)
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I ment left- and right hand limits. I forgot to mention that.